# Is it possible to use parameter from previous join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> SQL Error : The multi-part identifier "s.OrderType" could not be
>   bound.

```
from Table1 as c
inner join Table2 as s on c.RequestID = s.ReqID
inner join dbo.fn_getValues(s.OrderType) as gcd on c.ReqID = gcd.ReqID
```

Comment: You need to use `cross apply` instead of `inner join`, and move the `on` clause to a `where`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MS SQL

Comment: @HoneyBadger The problem is in the dbo.fn_getValues(**s.OrderType**) function parameter, may be i am getting your suggestion in wrong way, may you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @HoneyBadger
`from Table1 as c
Cross Apply Table2 as s  
Cross Aplly  dbo.fn_getValues(s.OrderType) as gcd
where c.RequestID = s.ReqID and c.ReqID = gcd.ReqID`
Is this that way you suggest it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `cross apply` instead of `inner join`, and move the `on` clause to a `where`:

```
from        Table1 as c
inner join  Table2 as s 
         on c.RequestID = s.ReqID
cross apply dbo.fn_getValues(s.OrderType) as gcd 
where       c.ReqID = gcd.ReqID
```

The problem is that for a join the table expression (the bit that follows `join`) must be unchangeable. If you join a table valued function this isn't true: the table expression is dependant on the value in a different table. That is why we have `cross apply`.